# Workflow retrieve information from Infopath-created form

Tags: workflow, infopath

I have an Infopath form with a submitter and a manager field. When the form is saved, I would like the workflow to start immediately, but how can I set it so that the workflow retrieves the information from the Infopath created fields? The two fields are people picker fields by the way.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you building workflow with SharePoint Designer or in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in Sharepoint Designer. So far I tried to create a new Workflow, and in Step 1: 'Start Approval process on Current Item with these users'. I clicked on these users, and tried to select the Participants. I click on 'Workflow lookup for a user', set the data source as the 'Current Item', but in the 'Field from Source', the Manager and submitter field is not listed. Is that supposed to be in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how about if you get the InfoPath Form to publish the two fields that you need into the Forms Library. You can then use the SharePoint Designer based workflow and grab the information that has been published into the fields.

If you were using Visual Studio, you could parse the XML document that the InfoPath form generates.

Comment: Ok, just to double check though, in InfoPath, each 'People Picker' field has three sub-fields. DisplayName, AccountID and AccountType. Which one should I publish? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: So lets see, the one that is going to give you the most information is going to be AccountId at least you have the login name which you can then resolve.

Comment: So I did 'Start Approval Process' on 'Current Item' with 'Current Item:Manager AccountID'. When I publish it, and I try to start the workflow automatically, it only shows two buttons, start / cancel. Is this normal, for a workflow created in Sharepoint Designer? Other workflows created in sharepoint at least will show the list of approvers, CC field, etc. All I get is a blank table, with just two buttons..

Comment: Yes thats normal, though you can customise the initial form and ask for more data if I remember correctly.